# Exception calling "InvokeSet" with "2" argument(s): "Unknown error (0x80005000)"

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've scoured the entire first 3 pages of google for this with no help *that has worked*

I'm trying to remotely update the Home and profile location in the Remote Desktop Services tab in Active Directory Users and Computers.

Here's my code:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DomainController -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock{   
    $User = [ADSI] "LDAP://CN=Paul Beenis,OU=Staff,DC=domain,DC=local"
    $User.psbase.Invokeset("TerminalServicesProfilePath","\\server\_Profile\pbeenis")
    $user.psbase.InvokeSet("TerminalServicesHomeDrive", "P:")
    $User.psbase.Invokeset("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory","\\server\_Home\pbeenis")
    $User.setinfo()
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
Exception calling "InvokeSet" with "2" argument(s): "Unknown error (0x80005000)"
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
+ PSComputerName        : DC03

Exception calling "InvokeSet" with "2" argument(s): "Unknown error (0x80005000)"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
    + PSComputerName        : DC03

Exception calling "InvokeSet" with "2" argument(s): "Unknown error (0x80005000)"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
    + PSComputerName        : DC03

The following exception occurred while retrieving member "setinfo": "Unknown error (0x80005000)"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember
    + PSComputerName        : DC03
```

**Things that have worked:**

- RDP into $DomainController and entering the commands into a local Powershell session
- Briefly using Enter-PSsession in the middle of my script, sending the 4 commands, the exit-pssession. However, this is unreliable and doesn't seem to work more than 1 time.

**Things that have NOT worked:**

- Suggestions on google tell you to copy tsuserex.dll and tsuserex.dll.mui from a windows 2012 server, paste it into your c:\windows\system32 and c:\windows\system32\en-us (respectively), then use regsvr32 command to register the DLL. This DID NOT work, I tried this with 3 different servers.

Comment: Are you actually sending strings or are you sending string objects?
`$User.psbase.Invokeset("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory","$serverpath")`

Comment: @Jordan thanks for the reply jordan, Yes I've done a test where I just hardcode the name into the command like in my example "\\server\_Home\pbeenis". Still errors out :(

Comment: According to [Generic ADSI Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/generic-adsi-error-codes) that appears to be "An invalid ADSI pathname was passed" error code. My first thought was a syntax issue, like not using $Using: in the scriptblock for the local scope variables, but if you tried hard coding the paths that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this problem is that I'm an idiot.

This code is correct

```
$User = [ADSI] "LDAP://$using:FullUserPath"
$User.psbase.Invokeset("TerminalServicesProfilePath","$using:ProfileLocation")
$user.psbase.InvokeSet("TerminalServicesHomeDrive", "$using:HomeDrive")
$User.psbase.invokeset("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory","$using:HomeLocation")
$User.setinfo()
```

However, my variables were incorrect (Which no one could have known by looking that this question.) I was assigning $FullUserPath before $DisplayName

```
$FullUserPath        = "CN=$DisplayName,$UserPath"
$DisplayName         = ($FirstName+" "+$LastName).ToString()
```

If you are receiving this error and you have followed the steps in my question under "Things that have NOT Worked" This means your variables were incorrect. Do a `write-host` on all of your variables and ensure they are good

Shoutout to @Jordan for pointing out that my variables could be wrong.